# Do you recommend using errno in new C APIs?

Tags: c, api, errno

Do you recommend using errno in new C APIs?

Should other methods of reporting problems like http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html be used instead?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

`errno` should be reserved to the C standard library, a program should treat it as a read only value.

Writing new code I strongly discourage using a errno-style global variable for error code checking. Say you have functions `a`, `b` reporting their status through `ab_error` then you must write things like this:

```
a();
if( ab_error == AB_NOERROR ) {
    b();
    if( ab_error == NO_ERROR ) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You see, that you rather quickly pile up nesting levels. If however your functions returned a error code you can write it this way:

```
int error_a;
int error_b;

if( (error_a = a()) == A_NOERROR
 && (error_b = b()) == B_NOERROR
){
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* test the error variables */
}
```

you can even chain multiple error conditions like this:

```
int error_a;
int error_b;
int error_c;

if( (error_a = a()) == A_NOERROR
 &&  ( (error_b = b()) == B_NOERROR
    || (error_c = c()) == C_NOERROR )
){
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* test the error variables */
}
```

Which is a lot more readable than if you'd scatter the whole thing over several nested if statements.

Comment: errno should not be treated as read only.  There are certain functions in the c library (eg strtol, strtod) for which errors can only be detected if the caller clears errno before calling.

Comment: @William: Sure, but what I meant: Don't use it to pass your very own error codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask yourself how well a global `errno` works in programs with multiple threads (or other forms of concurrency not containing separate copies of global variables). The typical conclusion is likely to be "not very well", and hence other solutions might be preferable.

Comment: It's not "a global `errno`", it's "**the** global `errno`", and it is defined not as `extern int` but as a macro which expands to an lvalue of type `int`, precisely because it is required to be thread-specific.

Comment: @R.: Thanks for the comment, you are right. My statement was based on experience on apparently non-compliant platforms, where the required behaviour of `errno` has not always been observed.

Comment: +1 since however it stresses the evilness of "global variables", even though errno is not exactly a global variable; however, my `man errno` says "errno may be a macro. errno is thread-local", not that it is surely a macro.